# How to get 4 Posts after the 5 most recent ones

Tags: query-posts, get-posts

Well, I think the question might be a bit confusing. But well, I want to get the recent 4 posts, ignoring the first five recent posts. So in short the sixth, seventh, eighth and ninth - most recent posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

WordPress provides a function called [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) that lets you get posts in any order.  Basically, `get_posts()` will retrieve the 5 most recent posts by default.

To get 4 posts, ignoring the 5 most recent, you'd set the `numberposts` and `offset` parameters - `offset` tells the function how many posts to skip.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'offset'      => 5,
    'orderby'     => 'post_date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Now you have an array of posts the 4 latest posts (ignoring the 5 most recent), ordered by date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the offset parameter - either on `pre_get_posts` hook ([see this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762)) for the 'main Loop':

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse50761_alter_query');
function wpse50761_alter_query($query){

      if( $query->is_main_query() ){
        //Do something to main query
        $query->set('offset',5);
      }
}
```

Or for subsequent secondary loops:

```
 //Using get_posts
 $my_offset_posts = get_posts(array('offset'=>5));

 //Using WP_Query object
 $my_offset_query = new WP_Query( array('offset'=> 5) );
```

(Of course other argument can be included in the argument array)